# Paperclip Processor - Convert image format dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, processor

I need to convert image format dynamically from paperclip custom processor.

My application have a rails 3.2.18 and paperclip 4.1

I am trying to convert format using 'convert' command as below.

```
extension = attachment.instance.resource_spec.extension
source      = @file
destination = Tempfile.new([@basename, extension])
destination.binmode

Paperclip.run("convert #{File.expand_path(source.path)} {File.expand_path(destination.path)}")
```

extension value will fetch from database.

Paperclip could not able to convert images to expected format through processor.

Please help if any

Thanks in advanced.

Nitin

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the key then using

```
rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=User
```

Which will regenerate all your images. Make sure you replace the class with the correct one for your app. See this link on **[thumbnail generation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation)** for more info.

via Devin M